# Combining chunks of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, jquery-events, dom-manipulation

I'm far from an expert at Javascript, and self taught, and I think this is probably Javascript 101, but I must have missed that lesson.

I've come up with the following code to make 7 rows in a table appear when I click the row in from of them (so every other row). I know it's not neat, but I was quite pleased with myself and it actually worked in the offline preview. However, when I upload my website, all the rows appear by default, and I have to click the rows above to make them disappear. They are supposed to all be hidden by default.

Thanks

This is the code:

```
<script>
$('.openRow1').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow1').toggle();
})
</script>

<script>
$('.openRow2').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow2').toggle();
})
</script>

<script>
$('.openRow3').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow3').toggle();
})
</script>

<script>
$('.openRow4').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow4').toggle();
})
</script>

<script>
$('.openRow5').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow5').toggle();
})
</script>

<script>
$('.openRow6').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow6').toggle();
})
</script>

<script>
$('.openRow7').click(function(){
    $('.hiddenRow7').toggle();
})
</script>
```

Comment: You should post any dom/css you have as well

Comment: Sorry, I know what's going on now. It's nothing to do with the Javascript at all. It's actually a css issue. For some reason, when I upload it the CSS, which is where it's being told to hide by default. Still I'm sure this code can be made a lot more efficient, so I'll leave the question live.

Comment: Did you set the CSS for `.hiddenRow*` to `display: none` to start with?

Comment: `made a lot more efficient` - One thing would be to have it all in single `<script>` block. At least it'd be easier to read and edit.

Comment: I'm betting on Mike Brant's comment. Also, do you really need a unique class for each of those rows?

Comment: @EddTillen, I hope you still take a look at my answer for a way to do this with much less code and much more easy to maintain code.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a better way to do this: http://jsfiddle.net/8fwdf/

DOM:

```
<div class="openRow">Open</div>
<div class="hiddenRow">Hidden</div>
<div class="openRow">Open</div>
<div class="hiddenRow">Hidden</div>
...
```

JS:

```
$('.hiddenRow').hide();
$('.openRow').click(function(){
    $(this).next('.hiddenRow').toggle();
})
```

You don't need to make a separate bind for each individual. You can use the jquery selector to select and apply a single bind on all of the elements. I used divs for this example but you can apply the same thing for other element types.

Note that I don't know what your DOM looks like so the `$(this).next()` part might need to be tweaked. Maybe you can figure that part out, or post your DOM and I can update.

Also, you could do this css and remove the `hide()` line:

```
.hiddenRow {
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To make this code more neat you can replace it with:

```
<script>
for(var i=1; i<=7; i++) {
    $('.openRow'+i).click(function(){
        $('.hiddenRow'+i).toggle();
    });
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
  <script>
for(var i=1; i<=7; i++) {
    $('.openRow'+i).click(function(){
        $('.hiddenRow'+i).toggle();
    }).css('visibility', 'hidden'); //this will make them invisible, but
}                                   //the elements will still take up that 
                                    //same amount of space. to completely remove
                                    //use *.css('display', 'none');

</script>
```

A jQuery is a live representation of the data that is in the DOM, so at any time you change a jQuery element, the webpage changes with it.